# Select Grouped Rows Having a certain Property

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to select only certain rows containing a certain property.  Here's a sample of the data I'm working with:

```
src_id                                              cand_source
------                                              -----------
201609-004d7bgNDFXuIrQPXwsXrOptt2PdTdeXsjV5RJ6_mEQ  mcp
201609-004d7bgNDFXuIrQPXwsXrOptt2PdTdeXsjV5RJ6_mEQ  mc2
201609-00WmbmuIp3cwAcTNTbrgb9tTVR0AKNf-RvjXcHWPEEQ  mc2
201609-00WmbmuIp3cwAcTNTbrgb9tTVR0AKNf-RvjXcHWPEEQ  mc2
201609-00WmbmuIp3cwAcTNTbrgb9tTVR0AKNf-RvjXcHWPEEQ  mc2
201609-00WmbmuIp3cwAcTNTbrgb9tTVR0AKNf-RvjXcHWPEEQ  mc2
201609-00WmbmuIp3cwAcTNTbrgb9tTVR0AKNf-RvjXcHWPEEQ  mc2
201609-00WmbmuIp3cwAcTNTbrgb9tTVR0AKNf-RvjXcHWPEEQ  mc2
201609-01My_orS795Hmomry3-JiCiBVimarRzRGQ9Cnornp8Q  mcp
201609-01My_orS795Hmomry3-JiCiBVimarRzRGQ9Cnornp8Q  mcp
201609-01My_orS795Hmomry3-JiCiBVimarRzRGQ9Cnornp8Q  mc2
201609-01My_orS795Hmomry3-JiCiBVimarRzRGQ9Cnornp8Q  mcp
201609-01My_orS795Hmomry3-JiCiBVimarRzRGQ9Cnornp8Q  mc2
201609-01noPFGBCqbH9jUB9MHNqPynjqW8cr24LJY917vSGTs  mc2
201609-01noPFGBCqbH9jUB9MHNqPynjqW8cr24LJY917vSGTs  mc2
201609-02ISoPEX0VVkQ0ogot49Q-e7K39Zyk2vdN1rB4Q-kl0  mc2
201609-02ISoPEX0VVkQ0ogot49Q-e7K39Zyk2vdN1rB4Q-kl0  mc2
201609-02LVZ8UqAaz7JCp3RAOTiIE7zH2mveiSQPBo6I6dHDc  mc2
201609-02LVZ8UqAaz7JCp3RAOTiIE7zH2mveiSQPBo6I6dHDc  mc2
201609-03dLH32kaKYVwIj4HiT1tZjCNgqgXiG-fvezX3S9QI4  mc2
201609-03dLH32kaKYVwIj4HiT1tZjCNgqgXiG-fvezX3S9QI4  mc2
201609-0421Jatpsk9T8GOD1M_GvDrnyV4dA41IL5tDeuTxGwU  mc2
201609-0421Jatpsk9T8GOD1M_GvDrnyV4dA41IL5tDeuTxGwU  mc2
201609-0421Jatpsk9T8GOD1M_GvDrnyV4dA41IL5tDeuTxGwU  mc2
201609-0421Jatpsk9T8GOD1M_GvDrnyV4dA41IL5tDeuTxGwU  mc2
201609-0421Jatpsk9T8GOD1M_GvDrnyV4dA41IL5tDeuTxGwU  mc2
201609-0421Jatpsk9T8GOD1M_GvDrnyV4dA41IL5tDeuTxGwU  mc2
201609-0421Jatpsk9T8GOD1M_GvDrnyV4dA41IL5tDeuTxGwU  mc2
201609-0421Jatpsk9T8GOD1M_GvDrnyV4dA41IL5tDeuTxGwU  mc2
201609-0421Jatpsk9T8GOD1M_GvDrnyV4dA41IL5tDeuTxGwU  mc2
201609-04HzM6NBIx_6QN91xzF9_p0RGfAQcRMeEhVFEPFZ8p4  mcp
201609-04HzM6NBIx_6QN91xzF9_p0RGfAQcRMeEhVFEPFZ8p4  mc2
201609-04HzM6NBIx_6QN91xzF9_p0RGfAQcRMeEhVFEPFZ8p4  mc2
201609-04HzM6NBIx_6QN91xzF9_p0RGfAQcRMeEhVFEPFZ8p4  mc2
201609-04HzM6NBIx_6QN91xzF9_p0RGfAQcRMeEhVFEPFZ8p4  mc2
201609-04HzM6NBIx_6QN91xzF9_p0RGfAQcRMeEhVFEPFZ8p4  mc2
201609-04HzM6NBIx_6QN91xzF9_p0RGfAQcRMeEhVFEPFZ8p4  mc2
201609-04HzM6NBIx_6QN91xzF9_p0RGfAQcRMeEhVFEPFZ8p4  mc2
201609-04HzM6NBIx_6QN91xzF9_p0RGfAQcRMeEhVFEPFZ8p4  mc2
201609-04JzR3AMxsfQvAeq1MAgjCtMhcaqt2Z_WNmuUlYLrLM  mc2
201609-04JzR3AMxsfQvAeq1MAgjCtMhcaqt2Z_WNmuUlYLrLM  mcp
```

What I want to do is select only the `src_id`s having at least one `cand_source` equaling `mcp`.  Here's what I've tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM schema.table
WHERE src_id IN (
    SELECT src_id
    FROM schema.table
    WHERE batch_id = ?
    GROUP BY src_id
    HAVING count(cand_source = 'mcp') > 1
)
ORDER BY src_id,
    match_score DESC
```

That, however, keeps giving me back clusters of `src_id`s that have no `cand_source`s equaling `mcp`.

---

It was pointed out that I'm simply overcomplicating matters.  Here's the solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM schema.table
WHERE src_id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT src_id
    FROM schema.table
    WHERE batch_id = ?
        AND cand_source = 'mcp'
)
ORDER BY src_id,
    match_score DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want the `src_id` that has mcp then a straight query with a `WHERE` clause is enough no need for conditional aggregation or anything.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    src_id
FROM
    Table
WHERE
    cand_source = 'mcp'
    AND batch_id = ?
```

If you want all of the records for each `src_id` that has at least 1 `cand_source` you can then join that back to the table to receive all of the records.

```
SELECT t.*
FROM
    Table t
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT src_id
     FROM Table
     WHERE cand_source = 'mcp'
       AND batch_id = ? ) d ON t.src_id = d.src_id
                            AND t.batch_id = ?
```

Or you can use a Common Table Expression with the awesome window functions to do it.

```
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT *, COUNT(CASE WHEN cand_source = 'mcp' THEN cand_source END) OVER (PARTITION BY src_id) as McpCount
    FROM
       Table
    WHERE
       batch_id = ?

)
SELECT *
FROM
    cte
WHERE
    McpCount > 0;
```

Comment: doh!  i overcomplicated matters.  thanks for simplifying things for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want just the source ids, then your subquery is all you need.  But, you want to count the number of matching values.  Here is verbose logic:

```
SELECT src_id
FROM schema.table
WHERE batch_id = ?
GROUP BY src_id
HAVING SUM(case when cand_source = 'mcp' then 1 else 0 end) > 1
```

A more concise version is:

```
HAVING SUM(cand_source = 'mcp'::int) > 1
```

Comment: isn't that the same as my `HAVING count(cand_source = 'mcp') > 1`?

Comment: @liltitus27 . . . No.  Your count is the same as `count(cand_source)`.  The comparison is irrelevant, because `count()` counts the number of non-`NULL` values.